# What's a good USB microphone for recording instruments?

Tags: usb, microphones, audio-recording, windows

I'm looking for a USB microphone to create recordings of instruments.

It must:

- be compatible with Windows 10 via USB
- have appropriate frequency range (I want it to include as much of the spectrum as possible so I can edit as I need)
- be reasonably cheap (I'm hoping to get it for under £20/$30)
- be in shops in the UK, so I'm not paying overseas delivery
- (obviously) produce the best quality recording possible

Bonus points for easy setup, easy compatibility with Audacity, and lower prices. Now I'm sure I've missed some things, so yell at me if y'all want more info.

Comment: Which instruments?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Piano mostly, though I might use it for any acoustic instrument.

Comment: `be in shops in the UK` - does this include online stores such as Amazon?

Comment: @bob Yes, if it's amazon.co.uk not amazon.com.

Comment: There's also some good answers on my own question [here](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/169/good-cheap-microphone-for-speech-voice-recording) (including your own :-) ). While my question was mostly about voiceover recording,  those microphones are probably also suitable for what you want to do. You'll also have to pay more than $30 if you want to get something really good.

Comment: heh. As an *investment*, a breakout box and a *good* mic would run you a few hundred. TOTALLY worth it tho. I have an old old old model maudio mbox2 and a pair of SM57s and the recordings are insanely good.

Answer (score 2):

For that price you won't be able to get anything too great, but there are a few options still. I'll recommend the same mic I recommended to @JonasCz [here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/173/155) a while back: the [Tonor USB Condenser Mic](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01142EPO4). For being a small, cheap mic, it has great quality.

**Specifications**

- Sensitivity: -55dB to 2dB
- Frequency response: 50Hz to 16KHz
- Sound-noise ratio: >36dB
- Cord length: ~2m
- Voltage: 1.5V

[image: Tonor USB Condenser Mic]

I've used this as a temporary mic and it easily gets the job done. But as @JourneymanGeek says, investing in a better mic (most people choose the SM57 as their first quality mic) and a small interface will be worth it assuming you'll be making use of this enough to warrant an upgrade.