# What makes a good condensor mic?

Tags: microphones

I am looking at a cheap-o mic and I want to know what to look for.  I am wanting to make some youtube videos but can't break the bank yet.
For example, an extremely cheap mic I found ([USB Studio Condenser Recording Microphone Vocal Singing Podcast Mic With Stand](http://www.ebay.com/itm/331590872220)) for GBP 18.99 has the following specs:

### Condenser Microphone

- Frequency response: 30Hz-20KHz
- Polar Pattern: Cardioid(0°-180°@1KHz > 12db)
- Signal to Noise Ratio:70dB
- Highest Sound Pressure Level:120dB S.P.L
- Sensitivity: 25mV/Pa (-32dB±2dB)
- Microphone amplifier function
- 2.5m cable with 3.5mm Jack &USB connector
- Power supply:USB DC5V

I really have no idea what to expect.

Comment: Could you tell and link us to the mic you found, and give us an idea of what you plan to do with it?  That will give us an idea of how good is "good enough" for your purposes.  It also helps if know how cheap is cheap (in other words, how much you are willing to spend).

Comment: I am wanting to make some youtube videos but can't break the bank yet.   eBay: http://pages.ebay.com/link/?nav=item.view&id=331590872220&alt=web

Comment: Additionally, [this question](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/169/good-cheap-microphone-for-speech-voice-recording?rq=1) might be relevant for you, though.

Comment: I'll take a look when I get home.