# A good microphone for voice recording / radio presenting

Tags: windows, microphones, audio-recording

I'm looking for a good microphone for recording speech (eg. for radio presenting), for about 60-70€.

I would prefer a USB one but I'll look into all suggestions.

Worth mention that I have a desktop but I don't have any external sound card.

The sound must have quality so no background noise and if it can come with a micstand that's even better.

A friend recommended me a [Blue Snowball Microphone](https://www.bluedesigns.com/products/snowball/) but already got 4 people saying otherwise because it breaks easily and I'm worried about that. And I still didn't find anything of my liking.

What do you recommend and why?

---

<sub>Note: Similar [question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/169/good-cheap-microphone-for-speech-voice-recording). (2015)</sub>